# Bash wonkyness on Ubuntu versus RHEL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, rhel5

Fellow faulters,

I'm playing around with a one liner that I've developed on a RHEL 5.4 box and I have it working perfectly:

```
TOTAL_RAM=`free | grep Mem: | awk '{ print $2 }'`; \ 
ps axo rss,comm,pid | awk -v total_ram=$TOTAL_RAM \
'{ proc_list[$2] += $1; } END { for (proc in proc_list) \
{ proc_pct = (proc_list[proc]/total_ram)*100; 
printf("%d\t%s\t%0.2f%\n", proc_list[proc],proc,proc_pct); }}' \
| sort -n | tail -n 10
```

Which outputs something like the following on my RHEL box:

```
3736    logmon  0.01%
4156    EvMgrC  0.01%
4692    hald    0.01%
5020    ntpd    0.02%
6252    sshd    0.02%
7784    cvd     0.02%
9224    snmpd   0.03%
13068   dsm_sa_datamgr3 0.04%
23320   dsm_om_connsvc3 0.07%
4249864 mysqld  12.90%
```

However on my Ubuntu 9.04 slice I get this:

```
awk: run time error: not enough arguments passed to printf("%d  %s      %0.2f%
")
        FILENAME="-" FNR=104 NR=104
33248   console-kit-dae 3.17
```

I think it has to be bash that is borking something, but I'm really not doing anything that should be *that* bash specific.  The RHEL box is running:

```
# yum info bash | grep -e Version -e Release
Version    : 3.2
Release    : 24.el5
```

And the Ubuntu box:

```
# apt-cache show bash | grep -e Version
Version: 3.2-5ubuntu1
```

I haven't dug into this super deeply, and thought I'd ping my fellow johnnys to see if you've ever run across this before.

/bow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does this command show on each system:

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

and since the error message is being produced by `awk`, what does this show:

```
awk --version | head -n 1
```

In addition to **chris's** suggestion for escaping the last % in the `printf` (which can be done with a backslash or by doubling the percent sign), it probably wouldn't hurt to put a line-continuation backslash at the end of the line before the `printf`.

Comment: So that was it, the RHEL box has GNU Awk 3.1.5 installed.  The Ubuntu slice came with mawk which is apparently compatible with GNU Awk except in this case....fail.  Once I installed gawk the script works fine.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

All I can say, is that it works perfectly fine on my Ubuntu 9.10. But your 4th `%` sign looks a bit strange to me - as if it relies on some not perfectly specified behaviour. Shouldn't it be escaped?

```
TOTAL_RAM=`free | grep Mem: | awk '{ print $2 }'`; \ 
ps axo rss,comm,pid | awk -v total_ram=$TOTAL_RAM \
'{ proc_list[$2] += $1; } END { for (proc in proc_list) \
{ proc_pct = (proc_list[proc]/total_ram)*100; 
printf("%d\t%s\t%0.2f%%\n", proc_list[proc],proc,proc_pct); }}' \
| sort -n | tail -n 10
```

Comment: For completeness (@Dennis): My BASH_VERSION on Ubuntu 9.10 is "4.0.33(1)-release", awk version: "GNU Awk 3.1.6"

Comment: BTW if you escape that last percent sign Awk complains:

awk: cmd. line:2: warning: escape sequence `\%' treated as plain `%'

Comment: @d34dh0r53: You're right, didn't notice that warning. I changed it to double `%`, as suggested by Dennis.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for memory percentage, you can do:

`top -b -n1`

You'll get some additional info, but it's easier to awk out. Top allows a batch mode such that all of the curses junk isn't piped to other applications.